# cannot find GoToElementState under VisualStateManager & VisualStateManager.GoToState returns false

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use animation using (For a windows 8 Phone Application)

```
VisualStateManager
```

But when i do

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState
```

it returns false. I have defined all the states and grids properly. I have a Grid Layout with name "ContentPanel" under the Main Grid Layout. Under "ContentPanel" i have rectangles on which this animation has to work. I have created all those rectangles dynamically using Code Behind. I have created all the states and animations in the same code and trying to run this above mentioned line.

I have googled and found different solutions to use GoToElementState() method. But i do not see this method in the class VisualStateManager class that i use. I know that is a static method, But it doesnt show up in the suggestions.

I Also tried to use ExtendedVisualStateManager class. Even this is not available.

Above all, I am not sure why my GoToState is not working. If i have the main element as a Grid (as LayoutRoot) then this animation is working. I used following lines

```
VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.ContentPanel);
```

// ContentPanel is the name of the layout
 where i have other rectangles on which the 
animations has to be binded. Then i used this command..

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "stateName", true) // Returns false. Nothing happens when this is executed. Can any one please suggest me with the right implementation of this.
```

Thanks,

Sri Tej N.

Comment: Where are your States defined? You need to call the method on the right object ... it's not clear from your question.

Comment: I have defined everything with in the code. There is just the ContentPanel Grid defined in the xaml file. In my code, i will be adidng around 16 rectangles in a 4 by 4 grid. Then on clicking a rectangle i will be calling a function there, i am defining the states and then calling this GoTOState() method.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. You're either not defining the state correctly, the animations are wrong, or not calling it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **Visual States** are under a `Grid`, then

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "stateName", true)
```

won't work because `this` is most likely a `Page`, which doesn't contain the **Visual States** directly.

and

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.YourGrid, "stateName", true)
```

won't work either because `GoToState`'s first parameter needs to be a type of `Control` - `Grid` doesn't inherit from `Control`.

You will need to use this one.

```
ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.YourGrid, "stateName", true)
```

Comment: I have actually completed this by placing all the UI elements in xaml code. Previously i tried to create them dynamically and thus it was a problem. But now as i have put them all with in the xaml i am able to use the normal visualstatemanager.gotostate command.

Comment: But my answer is still valid to your original question. If you think so please accept it as the answer.

Comment: do i need to import something for this ?? as i do not find this

    ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState

Comment: You need to add Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.